# PDO queries very slow over high latency, high bandwidth connection

Tags: postgresql

Running postgresql 9.x (9.1 - 9.3)

I have a custom web app built using php's PDO library. Every query in our app uses prepared statements (via our internal PDO wrapper library).

Our production system uses AWS EC2 small instances for the web server and RDS for the app server. 
For local development, my local machine serves as the web-server, and an office machine running Mac OSX (Mavericks) serves up the DB.

When I'm at work, I can typically ping my local office DB server and get 1-5ms ping times. Everything performs well, page load times are very speedy, my internal timer shows that PHP runs the page from start to end in about 12ms.

Now, the issue comes in when I take my work laptop home-- from home, I get about 50-60ms ping times to the office DB server. If I run my development machine at home, page times now take 5-10 seconds to load-- every time.  Granted, there are 4 db queries running per page load, it's very, very little data. I've tried TCP_NOWAIT settings, I've tried loading pgbouncer on my local machine with persistent connections to the remote db-- nothing has helped so far.

When timing the queries, we have a simple query that returns 100 bytes of data that runs in .0006 seconds locally to taking around 1 second to run remotely. Lastly, I'll say it appears to be related to latency only, no matter how much data a query returns, it's like it takes around 1 second longer than it normally would if running locally.. give or take.

I was simply wondering if anyone could help me resolve what this delay might be. It seems that every single query, no matter how much data, imparts a delay of around a second, give or take. The odd thing is that when I run PGAdmin on the my machine connecting to the remote DB, it takes nowhere near that much time to run simple queries.

Does anyone have any idea of other things to try? I'm not runnig an SSL DB connection, or using any compression, I'm willing to try if necessary, however, that's one thing I haven't gotten to work before, and I doubt that'll help with latency anyway.

Comment: Check the logs, PDO might be running a lot more queries than you expect.

Comment: Yep, set `log_statement = all` in `postgresql.conf` and see what's really getting run. If you've got some n+1 SELECT action going on that'd easily explain the issue. The other thing I'd be doing is using Wireshark to see what's actually happening on the protocol, see where exactly delays are occurring.